# Pandas Dataframe row value equals value above + 1

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I have a dataframe with the first week of each year. I'm trying to get a list of week numbers.

So essentially I need to fill na's with the number above (1) + 1.

Here's my code so far

```
FirstDay= {'Date':
           { 'Wk117' :'01-07-2016'
            ,'Wk118':'30-06-2017'
            ,'Wk119':'29-06-2018'
            ,'Wk120':'28-06-2019'


   }}

FirstDay=pd.DataFrame(FirstDay).reset_index()
#
FirstDay['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(FirstDay["Date"],dayfirst=True)
FirstDay['value']=int(1)

FirstDay=FirstDay.set_index('Date')
FirstDay=FirstDay.resample('W-FRI').mean()
FirstDay=FirstDay.fillna(0)

#FirstDay['value']=FirstDay['value'].astype(int)



for index, row in FirstDay.iterrows():
     if row['value']!=float(1):
        offset=row-1
        row['value']=offset['value']+1
```

Does anyone see why this isn't working?

Many thanks

Comment: first sort on Date and then use cumsum() function. It should do the job for you.

Comment: Thanks. Hasn't quite done what I was after. It's gone 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,... when really I need 1,2,3,4,5,

Comment: I added this code FirstDay=np.cumsum(FirstDay)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need replace missing values to `1` and then use [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
FirstDay=FirstDay.set_index('Date')
FirstDay=FirstDay.resample('W-FRI').mean()
FirstDay=FirstDay.fillna(1).cumsum().astype(int)
print (FirstDay.head(10))
            value
Date             
2016-07-01      1
2016-07-08      2
2016-07-15      3
2016-07-22      4
2016-07-29      5
2016-08-05      6
2016-08-12      7
2016-08-19      8
2016-08-26      9
2016-09-02     10
```

If need reset count for each year:

```
FirstDay['value'] = FirstDay.groupby(FirstDay['value'].fillna(0).cumsum()).cumcount().add(1)
print (FirstDay.head(10))
            value
Date             
2016-07-01      1
2016-07-08      2
2016-07-15      3
2016-07-22      4
2016-07-29      5
2016-08-05      6
2016-08-12      7
2016-08-19      8
2016-08-26      9
2016-09-02     10
```